# Flutter: Getx: How to load Dropdown widget after fetching values from Firestore database using Getx State Management

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, widget, dropdown, flutter-getx

My issue is : I am trying to fetch values(studentName) from my Firestore database and load it onto the DropDown widget. The problem that I a facing is that I am able to retreive the data from the Firestore database. But those values are being loaded into the Dropdown widget.
Actually there are two issues. 1) The onInIt method in my controller class is firing, I checked via print method. But the function inside is not working. I do not know why ? 2) The values are being loaded in the dropdown, probably becuase the onInIt method is not working properly.

My Controleller Class .

```
  

  // global variable of student names
  var studentNames = <String>[];
  RxString selectedStudent = ''.obs;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  
  
  @override
  void onInit() {
    print('2. onInit method is firing!');
    fetchStudentNames().then((value) {
      studentNames = value;
      print('3. firing fetch function: $value');
    });

    super.onInit();
  }
  Future<List<String>> fetchStudentNames() async {
    final studentCollection = _firestore
        .collection(FirestoreConstants.pathUserCollection)
        .doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection(FirestoreConstants.pathStudentCollection);
    final studentDocs = await studentCollection.get();

    if (studentDocs.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      final List<String> studentNamesList = [];
      for (final studentDoc in studentDocs.docs) {
        final studentId = studentDoc[FirestoreConstants.studentId];
        final studentName = studentDoc[FirestoreConstants.studentName];
        final fatherName = studentDoc[FirestoreConstants.fatherName];
        final surname = studentDoc[FirestoreConstants.surname];
        final createdBy = studentDoc[FirestoreConstants.createdBy];
        final createdById = studentDoc[FirestoreConstants.createdById];

        final student = StudentModel(
            studentId: studentId,
            studentName: studentName,
            fatherName: fatherName,
            surname: surname,
            createdBy: createdBy,
            createdById: createdById);
        // Combine the three fields into a single string
        final studentFullName = '$studentName $fatherName $surname';

        studentNamesList.add(studentFullName);
      }
      studentNames = studentNamesList;
      print('1. print studentNames List : $studentNamesList');
      return studentNamesList;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

My DropDown widget Class

```
  const AddStudentRecords({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Add Student Record'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: Sizes.dimen_12, horizontal: Sizes.dimen_14),
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 30.0,
            ),
            Obx(() {
              print('4. printing student: ${controller.selectedStudent.value}');

              return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                decoration: kTextInputDecoration.copyWith(
                  labelText: 'Select Student Name',
                  errorText: 'Student Name is Empty',
                ),
                value: controller.selectedStudent.value,
                isDense: true,
                onChanged: (student) =>
                    controller.selectedStudent.value = student!,
                items: controller.studentNames.map((student) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: student,
                    child: Text(student),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            }),
```

I have also used streams function and as well as Future<List> method as well. None of it works. Please help me find that error that I am overlooking. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Well thank you for the reference, I know there are lot of programmers who are against Getx, but I am prototyping it is not final app. That is why i am using it.